# Decal transparency and or culling problems Blender 2.93.1 Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

So this sounds like a known fail from my side, but i tested it so far that i realised Blender 2.82.1 is doing the right job, while 2.93.1 just give me a bad result. Is there something i just missed? I checked the material and texture. With and without alpha method it gives me the same issue. Also if i move the decal plane far from the main object i want the decal on it, the issue goes away. My problem is, i dont want to have the decal that far from my main object. Also its something that worked fine til now. This is 2.82.1[image] and this is 2.93.1[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the only solution, but the further away from the world center you go the more you get this issue. So its basically a clipping issue that goes over the transparency. Crank up the transparency bounces will not fix it. Better work on center of the world.